# How to grab Credit Card Type from Payment Gateway in WooCommerce to display on orders page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, firstdata

I use FirstData for my WooCommerce payment processing.  When I pull up orders in WooCommerce, it says: "Payment by Credit Card" but it does not tell me what type of credit card.  I just need to know if it was Visa, Mastercard, Discover, or AMEX.  We have an online store and a brick-and-mortar retail store.  For them to balance at the end of day they need to know the card type used at the order level.  We don't want to give them access to the payment gateway.

From a WooCommerce standpoint, there has to be a hand-off between the gateway and woo of some of the basic payment information.  I was hoping someone might know how/where I can hook credit card type into the Admin ORders page?

Any help is very appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without having to custom code any part of the extension, you can view a customers saved credit card tokens by going into the users profile. The only issue here is that the customer can remove their payment token thus not aligning with older orders that may have been paid with a different credit card. As a workaround however, you can at least view which cards the customer has stored and possibly used at your store with this information.

[image]